# Lost connection to MySQL server during query - Can't connect to MySQL Server

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I am trying to access new, fresh MySQL Server over corporate network, machines are using Windows. MySQL running version 8.0, python is 3.9.13

My code (Variant 1 `pymysql`)

```
import pymysql

def test_mysql_connection(host, port, username, password):
    try:
        # Establish a connection to the MySQL server
        connection = pymysql.connect(
            host=host,
            port=port,
            user=username,
            password=password
        )

        # If the connection was successful, print a success message
        print("Connected to MySQL database successfully!")

        # Close the connection
        connection.close()
    except pymysql.Error as err:
        # If there was an error, print the error message
        print(f"Error: {err}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

# Parameters
ip = "ip"
port = 1600
username = "admin"
password = "pass"

# Call the function to test the connection
test_mysql_connection(ip, port, username, password)
```

Result

```
Error: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query ([WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)')
```

Also i tryed to access via `sqlalchemy`
My code (Variant 1 `sqlalchemy`)

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.exc import OperationalError

db_username = "admin"
db_password = "pass"
db_server = "ip,1600"  # Add port 1600 to the server address
db_name = "db"
driver = "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server"

# Replace 'your_connection_string' with your actual database connection string
connection_string = f"mssql+pyodbc://{db_username}:{db_password}@{db_server}/{db_name}?driver={driver}"

try:
    # Create the engine and attempt to connect
    engine = create_engine(connection_string)
    engine.connect()
    print("Connection successful!")
except OperationalError as e:
    print("Error connecting to the database:", e)
```

Result

```
Error connecting to the database: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Timeout error [258].  (258) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Unable to complete login process due to delay in prelogin response (258)')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Since it is corporate network the only open port is `1600` that's the reason why I'm not using default one.
I saw multiple posts over internet about this problem and i tried many things.

- MySQL server is configured to listens to `1600` port
- Ofc Port `1600` is open on both client and server firewall (also in hardware firewall device)
- ODBC Driver 18.0 is installed as well
- Timeout and keep alive times are extended
- Query limit rows are extended none of this helps

When I try to access remotely via MySQL Workbench I can access from both client and server PC without any problems. I can create tables, write data, queries everything.

Any suggestions?

***Update 1***
Based on comment from @Gord I updates the `sqlalchemy` code with `MySQL ODBC 8.1 Unicode Driver` and got new error.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY000', '[HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.1(w) Driver]Missing option MULTI_HOST=1 (0) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.1(w) Driver]Missing option MULTI_HOST=1 (0)')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/dbapi)
```

***Update 2***
I added `MULTI_HOST=1` option to the code but have new error.
`connection_string = f"mssql+pyodbc://{db_username}:{db_password}@{db_server}/{db_name}?driver={driver}&MULTI_HOST=1"`

```
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.1(w) Driver]Unknown MySQL server host '1600' (11001) (2005) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.1(w) Driver]Unknown MySQL server host '1600' (11001) (2005)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY000', "[HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.1(w) Driver]Unknown MySQL server host '1600' (11001) (2005) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.1(w) Driver]Unknown MySQL server host '1600' (11001) (2005)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/dbapi)
```

***Update 3***
After update `mssql+pyodbc://` to `mysql+pymysql://` got new error again:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\gjykz5\Documents\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    engine.connect()
  File "C:\Users\gjykz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3315, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
  File "C:\Users\gjykz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 96, in __init__
    else engine.raw_connection()
  File "C:\Users\gjykz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3394, in raw_connection
    return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
  File "C:\Users\gjykz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3361, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\gjykz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 327, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\gjykz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 894, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\gjykz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 493, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\gjykz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Users\gjykz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\gjykz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\gjykz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\gjykz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 273, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\gjykz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 388, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "C:\Users\gjykz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 691, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "C:\Users\gjykz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\gjykz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\gjykz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 686, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\gjykz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 574, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\gjykz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 598, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'driver'
```

Comment: Your SQLAlchemy test is failing because you are trying to use the Microsoft SQL Server dialect (and ODBC driver) to connect to MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I missed that. I updated the code with `MySQL ODBC 8.1 Unicode Driver` I got new error. Will update the post.

Comment: `mssql+pyodbc://` is still the Microsoft SQL Server (mssql) dialect. You probably want to use `mysql+pymysql://`

Comment: I just adjusted it and new error pops up. I'm updating post.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.pymysql